# jQuery .prop("disabled", false) is not enabling an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having a problem re-enabling an input after it has been disabled on the page load.

I'm using two inputs to accept two dates, but I want it that the second input is not enabled until the first one has a value.

```
<div id="date1" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="date1-start" id="date1-startlbl">Start Date</label>
    <input name="date1-start" id="date1-start" type="date" data-role="datebox"data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d", "beforeToday": true}' data-theme="a" onchange="showdate()"/>
    <label for="date1-end" id="date1-endlbl">End Date</label>   
    <input name="date1-end" id="date1-end" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d", "beforeToday": true}' data-theme="a" onchange="datechart()"/>
</div>
```

The second input is disabled successfully on the page load with.

```
$("#date1-end").prop("disabled", true);
```

The first date has an `onchange` event that calls the following function

```
function showdate(){
    if ($("#date1-start").val() != null){
        if ($("#date1-end").val() != ""){
            datechart();
        }
        else{
            $("#date1-end").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#date1-end").trigger('change');
        }
    }
}
```

The function is called and `prop("disabled", false)` when reached fires without any errors, but the input remains disabled. The trigger('change') I am using is an attempt at refreshing the element but the same problem exists without it.

I have tried different variations of `.attr` from an older version of Jquery but I also get the same problem.

I am using Jquery 1.9.1, Jquery-mobile 1.3.1 and PhoneGap 2.7.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to disable a text input field if previous field is left blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929817/trying-to-disable-a-text-input-field-if-previous-field-is-left-blank)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/d9vzs/

This is not how you enable disable jQUery Mobile input elements.

It can be done with this functions:

```
$( "input" ).textinput( "disable" );


$( "input" ).textinput( "enable" );
```

Official documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#method-disable

Comment: This worked great. Should have looked through the Jquery mobile docs instead of just Jquery. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between your two functions?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII There was a typo, and I edited the second function to "enable".

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem some time ago:

```
$("#date1-end").prop("disabled", null);
```

@Gautam3164's answer is also good.

Comment: So unintuitive!! This works though - thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Try with `removeAttr` like

```
$("#date1-end").removeAttr("disabled");
```

You can also try with `prop` like

```
$("#date1-end").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: Sorry should have elaborated with .attr that I have also tried this, but I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: That was what I had originally been using but I get the same problem. I have read I may need to refresh the element after enabling it. Is there any truth in that?

Answer (score -4):

Prop is used just to get the value and set the value. Refer this http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$("#date1-end").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Scroll the page you've provided the link for, below you will see that prop also used to set the value.