# jquery prop.(“disabled”,true) not working, niether is .removeAttr('disabled');

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, when i would try to re-enable a button by running:

```
$("#reloadSuggestions").removeAttr('disabled');
```

and i also tried:

```
$("#reloadSuggestions").prop('disabled', false);
```

Anything i tried would not remove the disabled property, it would leave it blank. In the console if i ran `$("#reloadSuggestions").removeAttr('disabled');` it would remove it, but not when my actual code was running

PS reopeing this to answer it since it was [closed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469077/jquery-propdisabled-false-is-not-enabling-an-input) and nobody gave a real solution.

When the user clicks the button the button is disabled:

```
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <p class="mb-1 pull-left mt-5">Select up to ten audiences</p>
       <button class="btn-text mt-5 mb-1 pull-right" id="reloadSuggestions"><i class="far fa-sync-alt"></i></button>
  </div>



$("#reloadSuggestions").click(function(e) {

    fetchSuggestedTargeting();
    $("#reloadSuggestions").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

If the user did not fill in an input, i enable the button again:

```
function fetchSuggestedTargeting() {

    // set array of keywords
    var tagsinputKeywords = $("#interestTagInput").tagsinput('items')

    // Make sure user entered keywords
    if (tagsinputKeywords.length < 1) {

        $("#reloadSuggestions").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#searchSuggestedInterest").prop('disabled', false);;

        swal({
            title: "oops!",
            text: "Please enter atleast 1 keyword that describes your product.",
            imageUrl: "/alert-icon.png"
        });

        return;
    }
}
```

[here is an example of the issue](https://streamable.com/hi86e)

EDIT:

To clarify for the power tripping mods of SO, i am trying to re-enable a button after its been clicked and used to fetch data asynchronously, once the data is fetched, i want to re-enable the button for the user to be able to click it again.

When trying to set the `disabled` attribute back to `false` by running `$("#reloadSuggestions").prop('disabled', false);` **NOTHING** happens.

Not sure how this is a duplicate of someone asking how to change the property, the issue here is that the property won't change, regardless of what code is being ran unless i wrap it in a timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195089/discussion-between-ricks-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score -2):

Figured out that if i wrapped the code in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {

   $("#reloadSuggestions").prop('disabled', false);
}, 0);
```

My code would work, i thought of this solution because i was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) to solve a similar issue

> When you set a timeout, it actually queues the asynchronous code until the engine executes the current call stack.

Hope this helps anyone else who has this annoying issue.

Since apparently bugs don't exist, [here is an example of the issue](https://streamable.com/hi86e)

Comment: @PatrickEvans code is being ran on a click listener, element was already loaded and was disabled upon clicking to fetch data, then when the data is fetched the button is suppose to be enabled.